# Why is the solution to the equation $\ln(x)+\ln(3x+1) = 0$ not $x=\frac{-1}{4}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Wouldn't you just move the $ln(x)$ to the other side, then raise both sides to the power of $e$? And then you have the same bases equal to each other, so you get $3x + 1 = x$? From where you'd get $x =\frac{ -1}{4}$? Is there something wrong with this process?

This question was on a calculus exam so it does seem overly simple...any help is appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the solution to $3x + 1 = x$ is $x = -1/2$.

Answer (score 6):

We don't need to use esponential, indeed by $\log A+ \log B = \log (AB)$ with the conditions $x>0 \implies 3x+1>0$, we  have that

$$\ln x + \ln(3x+1)=\ln (3x^2+x)=0 \iff 3x^2+x=1 \iff 3x^2+x-1=0$$

then

$$x=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+12}}{6} \implies x=\frac{-1+ \sqrt{13}}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is and no, that's not the first thing you do. You should *first* impose the condition that both $x$ and $3x+1$ are elements of the domain of $\ln$, and *then* do any algebra you desire.

Answer (score 1):

I think you made a mistake of signs when you moved the $\ln x$ to the other side. It should be $\ln(3x+1)=-\ln(x)$.

*Now* you exponentiate both sides, and get $3x+1=\frac1x$.

After you're done solving that equation, remember to check that those solutions still work with the original equation; logarithms do not like negative inputs. Or you can do what the other answer says and keep track of which values of $x$ are valid as you go, and check your solutions against that at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you do that you get $\ln x = -\ln (3x+1)$

and when you use both sides as powers of $e$ to get

$e^{\ln x} = e^{-\ln (3x+1)} = \frac 1{e^{3x+1}}$ so that your first mistake.  Because one side negative you will get a reciprical.

$x =\frac 1{3x+1}$ so

$x(3x+1) = 1$

$3x^2 + x -1=0$

So $x = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{13}}6$ but $x > 0$ as logarithms of non-positives are not defined.

So $x = \frac {-1 + \sqrt{13}}6$

Alternatively you could have combined to get

$\ln x + \ln(x+3) = 0$

$\ln x(x+3) = 0$ so

$x(x+3) = 1$ and etc.

Comment: The solutions are wrong

Comment: Knew something was weird.....

Comment: @fleablood Now its fine.